# vue3 class component access props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-class-components

i use vue3 with class-component in typescript my class looks like:

```js
import {Options, Vue} from "vue-class-component";

@Options({
  props: {
    result: Object
  }
})


export default class imageResult extends Vue {
  currentImage = 0;

  getSlides(){
    console.log('result',this.$props.result); // not working
    console.log('result',this.result); // not working too
  }
```

My question is, how can i access and use the property within my class?

both *this.result* and *this.$props.result* throws me an error.

can someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

late answer but maybe it helps someone in the future.
works for me with vu3 & typescript

```
<script lang="ts"> 
import { Vue, prop } from "vue-class-component";

export class Props {
  result = prop<string>({ required: true });
}

export default class Foo extends Vue.with(Props) {
  test(): void {
    console.log(this.result);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is to follow the documentation on using Typescript with vue using class component: [enter link description here](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/props-definition.html)

in order to fix your code I think this should work:

```
import {Vue} from "vue-class-component";
import {Component} from "vue-class-component";

// Define the props by using Vue's canonical way.
const ImageProps = Vue.extend({
  props: {
    result: Object
  }
})

// Use defined props by extending GreetingProps.
@Component
export default class ImageResult extends ImageProps {
  get result(): string {
    console.log(this.result);
    // this.result will be typed
    return this.result;
  }
}
```

Comment: That would only work for Vue 2. The API has changed for Vue 3.

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation of vue for typescript components? I just followed the vue-class-component library you are using. With official vue 3 core is more straight forward: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props

Comment: Those docs refer to the Options API of Vue itself. But the OP is using `vue-class-component` with Vue 3. The question specifically relates to using that library.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!
But this is, as tony said, for vue2. I am looking for the latest version 3